# Creating easy to use Static Libraries Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks

I am creating a static library which I am wrapping into a .framework for other developers to use, and one thing that I'm really trying to provide the eventual users of this library/framework is ease of use, I want them to be able to almost just drop it into their Application's Frameworks and start using it.

However I've come across a couple of things which is making the end job of the developer, bit by bit more long, not difficult but just extra steps they need to do in order to get things working.

For example, I'm using SQLite in my library so I will need that the user includes that library into their project as well as mine.

Also I am using some categories inside my library so, I will need the developer to also set their Other Linker Flags to include "-ObjC", I was trying to avoid categories to work around this one but it just isn't worth it.

I can imagine I might come across more things I will need and that will require extra set up work for the developer.

Can anyone share any tips on how to make the end user or developers life easier or anything relative to my concerns ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Open Source frameworks i've used usually has very similar stuff as yours above where you have to include some frameworks and add `-ObjC` and `-all_load` to the Linker Flags. As long as you provide proper documentation (and screenshots if the framework is targeted towards the less proficent) then you should be okay for distribution